# Typeset algorithms in restructured text and mathjax

Tags: algorithm, mathjax, typesetting

I'm using restructured text to write pages for a Pelican site and I can display mathematical notation and equation using MathJax.

I would like to also typeset algorithms similar to LaTeX's `algpseudocode` package, are there
any similar tools or methods for restructured text or mathjax?

I also need to be to use mathematical notation inside the algorithms.